# Laravel | How to assign some particular permissions to some particular users

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, acl, roles

I am looking for a way in Laravel ACL to assign some particular permissions to one or more particular users without using any packages. I am using Laravel 5.5 on my local PC.
I came up with two solutions but when I started looking for more solutions on Google, I found out that my own solutions has some disadvantages so I intent to find a out a more feasible or if possible the optimal solution.
My solutions -

> 1. Making a new pivot table directly for users and permissions.
>      *Disadvantage - There would be no meaning of making and assigning roles and role_user pivot table if I directly make permission_user pivot table.*
> 2. Make a new role(name it **Special** role for later use) having the desired permissions and assign it to desired users.
>      *Disadvantage - If a user, not having permissions to make/assign permissions or make new roles but has permissions to assign the existing roles, can assign the **Special** role to some unauthorized users.*

**EDIT**
After receiving a couple of responses I got that people are not understanding what I am trying to say.
So let me give an example which will clear out the confusions
To achieve what I am trying to say I will take the minimum of what is needed.
So for example,

> In my app I have a user - user2 and a role - B.
>   B has been assigned a permission only to view roles(the index method for role controller).
>   And user2 has assigned role B.
>   Now what would I do(other than the solutions that I have mentioned above in this post) if I want to assign a permission, let say permission to create permissions, to user2.

Comment: I use this plus a role_permissions pivot table https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization Idk if it's the best solution, but I never had an issue with it

Comment: @Indra What you are saying is true but my question is how to assign the particular permissions in the first place. Authorizing and allowing will be done later.

Comment: Oh... I use a seeder initially and then I update them as the app evolves. Quite sure it's not the smartest way but it works and that's all I care about sometimes tbh.